# apply custom theme in activity for every edit texts

Tags: android, themes

I want to change background shape for all edit texts in my app. I created xml file in the drawable folder like this.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="1sp" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    <solid  android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <padding android:top="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

And I created style tag in the styles.xml file.

```
     <style name="editTxt_theme" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittxt_shape</item>
    </style>
```

And I apply this theme into my activity. But it applied all of other widgets. Is there anything wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: "But it applied all of other widgets" what do you meant by this?? you have widgets for your app? and edit text style also changed for your widgets?

Comment: I mean all of textviews and actionbars have been changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to define a theme for your app in your `styles.xml` and use `android:editTextStyle` to define your custom style for all `EditText` views like so:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/CustomEditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomEditTextStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittxt_shape</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:enabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

All that's left now is tell your app to use your theme in your manifest:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme" >
    ...
</application>
```

This way, you won't need to put `style` attributes on all your `EditText` views.

Comment: I haven't really found a good reference for it, but you can snoop around [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html). The pattern is usually `viewNameStyle` (e.g. `buttonStyle`, `textViewStyle`).

Comment: But I cannot enter value in the edit text. And action bar have gone.

Comment: You can set other properties of the `EditText` in the custom style as well. See updated answer above and try setting the `android:enabled` property to true. You can define anything related to the respective views in there. If it still doesn't work, it would help if you post your updated code. This is what I've been doing ever since and never had problems with it.

Comment: You're welcome! Enjoy this new trick, it's very useful for custom themes. :)